# location-based Augmented Reality Framework (Android, iOS) with 3D Models?

Tags: android, ios, geolocation, augmented-reality

I'm looking for a location-based (not marker-based) augmented reality framework allowing 3d models in both Android and iOS.

I'm not interested in POIs (Point-of-interest) where there is already plenty of frameworks and lots of documentation to do it ourselves such as this:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/42266/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-location-based

Basically, using the same kind of principle as in the article above, but instead of displaying just a label, there could be for example a building-size cube; we could go around it, look down & up and the perspective would change accordingly.

Something that feeds the phone GPS coordinates (and 3 angles) to the "point of view" of an overlay OpenGL view and is open enough to let me add what I want to the OpenGL world (maybe using real-world coordinates too), with some optimisation.

it's for integration in an app with other features so using some of the AR browser available out there doesn't work either.

All I could find was pretty expensive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also trying to achieve this, did you find a way?

Answer (score 3):

not sure whether you had a look at the [Wikitude SDK](http://www.wikitude.com/products/wikitude-sdk/) during your research. The SDK delivers exactly this functionality for iOS and Android. You can position 3D models at any geo-location you like - even work with relative locations.

There is also a [comparison table](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks) on available AR SDKs available online. Have a closer look at the column GPS to filter for location-based libraries.

Comment: Use Wikitude if you are ready to shell out 1499 euros.